# CentOS 5.5: Enabling local file system quotas - Failed

Tags: centos5, disk-space-utilization

I have installed CentOS 5.5 servern with a KDE desktop. Everything seems to be functioning okay but I keep getting this error when I turn on my computer (the log while starting up). I have installed apache, mysql, phpmyadmin, dovecot and using a tutorial I edited fstab from:

**Original FSTAB file**

```
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

**Modified FSTAB file in use (according to the tutorial I used)**

```
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /                       ext3    defaults,usrquota,grpquota        1 1
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

All processes start okay but the parameter Enabling local file system quotas returns failed. What are the implications of this? How can I correct this error?

When I type `quotacheck -a` in the terminal it returns

```
quotacheck: WARNING - Quotafile //aquota.user was probably truncated. Can't save quota settings.

quotacheck: Cannot remount filesystem mounted on / read-only so counted values might not be right.

Please stop all programs writing to filesystem or use -m flag to force checking
```

Comment: Does the file `/aquota.user` exist?

Comment: yes it does exist

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `/aquota.user` and `/quoata.group` files? Run `quotacheck -cug /` to create them if you haven't.

Comment: they both exist, do i still run the command?

Comment: Yeah; it'll properly initialize the file. Boot into single user mode to run it, so nothing else is going on.

Comment: should i run it as root?

Comment: Yes. (That's implied by single-user mode, btw.)

Comment: I did that n I get the error bad number of arguments. Utility for checking and reparing quota files. quotacheck [-gucfinvdmMR] [-F <quotaformat>] filesystem|-a

Comment: Did you include the `/` at the end?

Comment: @mattdm - ooppss.. sorry I did that and the output is
quotacheck: Cannot remount filesystem mounted on / read-only so counted values might not be right.
Please stop all programs writing to filesystem or use -m flag to force checking.

Comment: @mattdm - I ended all active programs before executing the command should I add -m at the end?

Comment: "Ending all active programs" entails more than you think it does. Not just the programs you see, but everything you don't as well. The only way to do this is to enter single user mode. (That said, `-M`, in caps, might work, although you risk getting slightly invalid data.)

Comment: I am working as the root user, i'll logout and try again and get back with the results

Comment: @mattdm - After I run it with -M will I recieve any outputs because it looks like its hung

Comment: It's scanning the filesystem. Please hold. :) You can run it with `-v` or `-vv` to see what's going on.

Comment: @mattdm - thanks for all the help! I'll keep you updated as soon as it finishes but by the looks of it, its still at it.

Comment: @mattdm - I kept it going for hours and nothing happened, actually I left my computer on all nite long and well it was still there. Do you know approx. how long it takes?

Comment: Shouldn't take that long. I suggest switching into single-user mode (`sudo telinit 1`) and running from there. Use the `-vv` option this time to watch the progress. Before you do that, though, type `dmesg` and look for disk errors.